# Is a blank Security.cipherSeed okay?

Tags: security, cakephp

I'm responsible for installing and managing a webapp written by an external developer.

I'm not familiar with CakePHP, and the developer instructed me to leave `Security.cipherSeed` in `core.php` as a blank string. Is this acceptable?

I ask because I've been poking through the code, and I am less than confident in the developer's coding chops.

The webapp is accessible via HTTPS only if that makes a difference.

Comment: Is it still used anywhere? What did he say about the salt value? It sounds like intentionally weakening the security unnecessarily, but I don't know enough to say for sure. You should probably ask the developer why he thinks it should be blank though.

Comment: Turns out it's (currently) unused in the codebase. I'm pushing to fork the app, anyway. The more code I read, the scarier it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this value is used with [`srand()`](http://php.net/srand) (when using `Security::cipher`, **update**: note that the Cookie component currently uses `Security::cipher` by default for encrypting/decrypting cookies **/update**), passing an empty string might trigger a warning, saying that parameter 1 is expected to be long instead of string.

Also this will cause a random seed to be generated by PHP automatically, which will make decrypting text that was encrypted using [`Security::cipher()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html#Security%3a%3acipher) impossible (or let's say kinda complicated at least).

So, if the PHP installation or the CakePHP source isn't modified so that either `srand()` will use a static seed automatically (that would be very bad), or that `Security::cipher` retreives a seed from somewhere else (also a bad idea), then you probably shouldn't leave it blank, even if you do not use `Security::cipher` yet. Though actually you shouldn't use `Security::cipher` anyways, it's already deprecated, however defining a value but not yet using it should cause no harm, not defining a value and trying to use it most probably will.

To make sure everything's fine, check the source whether `Security::cipher` is used, and if that's the case, then write some tests around its use to make sure everything works as expected. Also try contacting the developer and ask him why he thinks it should be left blank, maybe there's some hidden magic going on, who knows...

In a nutshell, if `Security::cipher` is not used, and definitely never will be used, then it should be ok, leave it blank or fill it with your favorite poem, it shouldn't matter, if it *is* used or you are planning to use it, then don't leave that value blank, or even better, if possible use [`Security::rijndael()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html#Security%3a%3arijndael) instead.

Comment: Note that it will also be removed in future versions: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/1464

Comment: Great answer. It's currently unused, and I've decided to fork the codebase, as I've discovered the author's idea of implementing user groups is to simply hide the links to the functionality that group shouldn't have access to. If they know the URL, however …